# Can Investigating have negative effects?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So far I have been going through all possibilities when I can choose Investigate when talking to characters. Can this have a negative effect at any point or should I just go for it?

Comment: pretty sure it doesn't ever, but this is sort of hard to answer definitively

Comment: It never did in ME or ME2.

Comment: @BenBrocka It is only hard to answer definitively if the answer is it can not have negative effects, by the looks of it that is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have no hard evidence to support this (not sure any exists without looking at the game code) in all my playthroughs there was never a negative effect for investigating/exploring all dialog. Same goes for talking to people just to hear the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Investigate simply gives you additional background about the story and its characters.  It is neither required for good outcomes, nor can it cause bad outcomes.